# ASP.NET Database Connect

Tags: asp.net, database, connection

Hello when i run my application on server, the connection doesn't open
--> my dataset is still closed

```
Dim strconnect As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + "rootPath" + "\" + "VSS_TESTDB.mdb" + "Persist Security Info=False"


Dim objConnection As New OleDbConnection(strconnect)

Dim sql As String = "SELECT VSS_Files.id, VSS_Files.filename,VSS_Files.dateOfCreation,VSSDirs.dir  FROM VSS_Files , VSSDirs Where VSS_Files.dir_id = VSSDirs.id;"


Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, objConnection)

Dim myDataReader As OleDbDataReader
        myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

what can i do?

greetings tyzak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an OleDbConnection using an OleDbConnectionStringBuilder to connect to the database.

For example:

```
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
builder.DataSource = Path.Combine(rootPath, "VSS_TESTDB.mdb")
builder.PersistSecurityInfo = False

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ToString())
Using command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT VSS_Files.id, VSS_Files.filename,VSS_Files.dateOfCreation,VSSDirs.dir  FROM VSS_Files, VSSDirs Where VSS_Files.dir_id = VSSDirs.id;", connection)
    connection.Open()
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        'Do something
    End Using
End Using
```

**EDIT**: Your problem is probably that you put quotes around `rootPath`.  The `Data Source` of your connection string is `DataSource=rootPath\VSS_TESTDB.mdb`.  I assume that you actually want it to have the *value* of the `rootPath` variable.

Also, you need to open the connection.

Finally, you should close the connection and the DataReader using the `Using` statement.

See my updated example.

Comment: hi, sorry i post some more code:
Dim strconnect As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + "rootPath" + "\" + "VSS_TESTDB.mdb" + "Persist Security Info=False"
        
Dim objConnection As New OleDbConnection(strconnect)

Dim sql As String = "SELECT VSS_Files.id, VSS_Files.filename,VSS_Files.dateOfCreation,VSSDirs.dir  FROM VSS_Files , VSSDirs Where VSS_Files.dir_id = VSSDirs.id;"
        

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, objConnection)

Dim myDataReader As OleDbDataReader
        myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty vague, and it is difficult to properly diagnose from one line of code.  Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. You need to assign this connection string to a connection object.
2. See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for the full and proper form for connection strings.